# C# fractions calculator

Tags: c#, fractions

I'm trying to make a complex fraction calculator (eg: 1 3/4 + 3 4/5). I've made the multiplication:

```
static public Fraction operator *(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs)
{
    Fraction result;
    result = new Fraction();

    result.Denom = lhs.Denom * rhs.Denom;
    result.Num = ((lhs.Whole * lhs.Denom) + lhs.Num) *
            ((rhs.Whole * rhs.Denom) + rhs.Num);

    result.Whole = result.Num / result.Denom;
    result.Num = result.Num % result.Denom;
    return result;
}
```

But the others are becoming difficult. Can I have some help on making one for division and one for addition?

This is my attempt at division:

```
static public Fraction operator /(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs)
{
    Fraction result;
    result = new Fraction();

    result.Num = lhs.Num * rhs.Denom;
    result.Denom = lhs.Denom * rhs.Num;

    result.Whole = result.Num / result.Denom;
    result.Num = result.Num % result.Denom;
    return result;
}
```

When I try to figure it out, I keep messing things up and it doesn't go down so smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing missing functions.

Comment: *I keep messing things up and it doesn't go down so smoothly.* This isn't specific enough. Specify what goes in, what processing happens, what comes out and what you expect to come out. Ask *one question*, not a load of questions in the form of "how can I do this bunch of stuff?"

Comment: So, you need someone to teach you programming basics?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this article:
[Fraction class in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C)

Simple solution:

```
static public Fraction operator /(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs)
{
    return lhs * new Fraction(rhs.Denom, rhs.Num);
}
```

My fraction class:

```
public struct Fraction : IEquatable<Fraction>
{
    long _numerator;
    public long Numerator
    {
        get { return _numerator; }
        private set { _numerator = value; }
    }

    long _denominator;
    public long Denominator
    {
        get { return _denominator == 0 ? 1 : _denominator; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Denominator cannot be assigned a 0 Value.");

            _denominator = value;
        }
    }

    public Fraction(long value)
    {
        _numerator = value;
        _denominator = 1;
        Reduce();
    }
    public Fraction(long numerator, long denominator)
    {
        if (denominator == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Denominator cannot be assigned a 0 Value.");

        _numerator = numerator;
        _denominator = denominator;
        Reduce();
    }


    private void Reduce()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Numerator == 0)
            {
                Denominator = 1;
                return;
            }

            long iGCD = GCD(Numerator, Denominator);
            Numerator /= iGCD;
            Denominator /= iGCD;

            if (Denominator < 0)
            {
                Numerator *= -1;
                Denominator *= -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot reduce Fraction: " + exp.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return (Numerator == other.Numerator && Denominator == other.Denominator);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Fraction))
            return false;

        return Equals((Fraction)obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32((Numerator ^ Denominator) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.Denominator == 1)
            return this.Numerator.ToString();

        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(this.Numerator);
        sb.Append('/');
        sb.Append(this.Denominator);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static Fraction Parse(string strValue)
    {
        int i = strValue.IndexOf('/');
        if (i == -1)
            return DecimalToFraction(Convert.ToDecimal(strValue));

        long iNumerator = Convert.ToInt64(strValue.Substring(0, i));
        long iDenominator = Convert.ToInt64(strValue.Substring(i + 1));
        return new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);
    }
    public static bool TryParse(string strValue, out Fraction fraction)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
        {
            try
            {
                int i = strValue.IndexOf('/');
                if (i == -1)
                {
                    decimal dValue;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(strValue, out dValue))
                    {
                        fraction = DecimalToFraction(dValue);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    long iNumerator, iDenominator;
                    if (long.TryParse(strValue.Substring(0, i), out iNumerator) && long.TryParse(strValue.Substring(i + 1), out iDenominator))
                    {
                        fraction = new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        fraction = new Fraction();
        return false;
    }

    private static Fraction DoubleToFraction(double dValue)
    {
        char separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];

        try
        {
            checked
            {
                Fraction frac;
                if (dValue % 1 == 0)    // if whole number
                {
                    frac = new Fraction((long)dValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    double dTemp = dValue;
                    long iMultiple = 1;
                    string strTemp = dValue.ToString();
                    while (strTemp.IndexOf("E") > 0)    // if in the form like 12E-9
                    {
                        dTemp *= 10;
                        iMultiple *= 10;
                        strTemp = dTemp.ToString();
                    }
                    int i = 0;
                    while (strTemp[i] != separator)
                        i++;
                    int iDigitsAfterDecimal = strTemp.Length - i - 1;
                    while (iDigitsAfterDecimal > 0)
                    {
                        dTemp *= 10;
                        iMultiple *= 10;
                        iDigitsAfterDecimal--;
                    }
                    frac = new Fraction((int)Math.Round(dTemp), iMultiple);
                }
                return frac;
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Conversion to Fraction in no possible due to overflow.", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Conversion to Fraction in not possible.", e);
        }
    }
    private static Fraction DecimalToFraction(decimal dValue)
    {
        char separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];

        try
        {
            checked
            {
                Fraction frac;
                if (dValue % 1 == 0)    // if whole number
                {
                    frac = new Fraction((long)dValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal dTemp = dValue;
                    long iMultiple = 1;
                    string strTemp = dValue.ToString();
                    while (strTemp.IndexOf("E") > 0)    // if in the form like 12E-9
                    {
                        dTemp *= 10;
                        iMultiple *= 10;
                        strTemp = dTemp.ToString();
                    }
                    int i = 0;
                    while (strTemp[i] != separator)
                        i++;
                    int iDigitsAfterDecimal = strTemp.Length - i - 1;
                    while (iDigitsAfterDecimal > 0)
                    {
                        dTemp *= 10;
                        iMultiple *= 10;
                        iDigitsAfterDecimal--;
                    }
                    frac = new Fraction((int)Math.Round(dTemp), iMultiple);
                }
                return frac;
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Conversion to Fraction in no possible due to overflow.", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Conversion to Fraction in not possible.", e);
        }
    }

    private static Fraction Inverse(Fraction frac1)
    {
        if (frac1.Numerator == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation not possible (Denominator cannot be assigned a ZERO Value)");

        long iNumerator = frac1.Denominator;
        long iDenominator = frac1.Numerator;
        return new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);
    }
    private static Fraction Negate(Fraction frac1)
    {
        long iNumerator = -frac1.Numerator;
        long iDenominator = frac1.Denominator;
        return new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);

    }
    private static Fraction Add(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2)
    {
        try
        {
            checked
            {
                long iNumerator = frac1.Numerator * frac2.Denominator + frac2.Numerator * frac1.Denominator;
                long iDenominator = frac1.Denominator * frac2.Denominator;
                return new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            throw new OverflowException("Overflow occurred while performing arithemetic operation on Fraction.", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while performing arithemetic operation on Fraction.", e);
        }
    }
    private static Fraction Multiply(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2)
    {
        try
        {
            checked
            {
                long iNumerator = frac1.Numerator * frac2.Numerator;
                long iDenominator = frac1.Denominator * frac2.Denominator;
                return new Fraction(iNumerator, iDenominator);
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            throw new OverflowException("Overflow occurred while performing arithemetic operation on Fraction.", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while performing arithemetic operation on Fraction.", e);
        }
    }

    private static long GCD(long iNo1, long iNo2)
    {
        if (iNo1 < 0) iNo1 = -iNo1;
        if (iNo2 < 0) iNo2 = -iNo2;

        do
        {
            if (iNo1 < iNo2)
            {
                long tmp = iNo1;
                iNo1 = iNo2;
                iNo2 = tmp;
            }
            iNo1 = iNo1 % iNo2;
        }
        while (iNo1 != 0);

        return iNo2;
    }

    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction frac1) { return (Negate(frac1)); }
    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return (Add(frac1, frac2)); }
    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return (Add(frac1, -frac2)); }
    public static Fraction operator *(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return (Multiply(frac1, frac2)); }
    public static Fraction operator /(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return (Multiply(frac1, Inverse(frac2))); }

    public static bool operator ==(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return frac1.Equals(frac2); }
    public static bool operator !=(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return (!frac1.Equals(frac2)); }
    public static bool operator <(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return frac1.Numerator * frac2.Denominator < frac2.Numerator * frac1.Denominator; }
    public static bool operator >(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return frac1.Numerator * frac2.Denominator > frac2.Numerator * frac1.Denominator; }
    public static bool operator <=(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return frac1.Numerator * frac2.Denominator <= frac2.Numerator * frac1.Denominator; }
    public static bool operator >=(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) { return frac1.Numerator * frac2.Denominator >= frac2.Numerator * frac1.Denominator; }

    public static implicit operator Fraction(long value) { return new Fraction(value); }
    public static implicit operator Fraction(double value) { return DoubleToFraction(value); }
    public static implicit operator Fraction(decimal value) { return DecimalToFraction(value); }

    public static explicit operator double(Fraction frac)
    {
        return ((double)frac.Numerator / frac.Denominator);
    }
    public static explicit operator decimal(Fraction frac)
    {
        return ((decimal)frac.Numerator / (decimal)frac.Denominator);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer, as it does not answer the question directly (in fact, the question is not even answerable in its current form as it doesn't highlight a specific problem). You will soon have enough rep to post comments if you post useful answers to other questions.

Comment: In addition, we ususally don't accept just-a-link answers. Because links can die. For a proper answer you'd have to quote the relevant parts here. But on this question that's debatable.

Comment: I wasn't having trouble with that. I'm having trouble with integrating whole numbers into it.